# How to proper xml in shell

Tags: xml, shell, parsing

1st post:

I started a project which uses a shell executable under Linux, and it reads xml files within folders, creates new xml files and do logical comparations there...

I started and there are already a few lines of code (150) but i want to start over again to make it with really clean xml.

Do you have any recommendations what to read to get into it.
How do it put all the read data in the RAM of the PC instead of read it over and over again within each loop where logical comaparions are made so its fast and effective?

Thats the project:

https://github.com/docduckington/folderagency

I wanted to use shell instead of python or c/c++/java

Thanks for any tips and recommendations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for your reply. Well its supposed to be a general question. Why should I post bad code when I first wanna read and lern it. maybe its the wrong place to ask this question...

Comment: So you are searching for a tutorial? Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok i will do it in your described way, thanks. here a direct question to it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640914/attributing-the-right-data-out-of-xml-according-to-found-string-in-shell-parsing